# Is there any way to use << operator with stringstream and strings with spaces?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I've ran across this problem while coding my little parser and noticed that stringstream seem to not receive any more data after the space character is met.

Basically

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << "Test test";
std::string str;
stream >> str;

std::cout << str;
```

will print "Test" instead of "Test test". Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: `std::cout << stream.rdbuf();` if you want to dump entire content to `cout`.

Comment: You could make a wrapper of a `std::string` only to overload `operator>>` with your own behaviour. The problem is: Whats the condition to stop reading?

Comment: stringstream *does* receive data after the space character. However, `>>` doesn't read data after the space.

Comment: Is there any reason to read from the stream rather than using `str()` once you are done writing to it (and use an `syd::ostringstream`)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `std::getline`:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(stream, str);

std::cout << str; // "Test test"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the whole "Test test" in one line. I guess I should be more specific. My code is more likely to look like this:


    stream << someString1 << " something " << someString2 << perhapsAnInteger;

Comment: If I have read the doc correctly, the issue is not with `<<` but with the `>>` operator, `std::getline` **extracts** the string from the stream (where all of it is safely stored). Check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline NOTE: This post is directed at the OP's comment, I am not trying to change 0x4...'s answer

Comment: @user1255410 What do you mean by you don't have the text "in one line"? Does the text in the stream consist of new lines?